# Problemas con wow.js y animate.css en adobe muse

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy utilizando la versión de adobe muse 17.1, hace unos días todo funcionaba correctamente con las animaciones, pero de pronto las animaciones ya no funcionan más, y no entiendo porqué. Tengo varias teorías:

1.-Fallo de actualización de adobe muse.

2.-Fallo mío en el diseño, habré tocado algún botonsito (he desinstalado e instalado d nuevo)

3.-Adobe me está castigando por utilizar una versión pirata (juro comprarme la versión de pago si todo funciona correctamente, de momento no me convence).

He hecho una versión de prueba bastante sencilla para mostrarla por aquí, el código no es mi fuerte, aunque no veo ningún fallo importante o no soy capaz de detectarlo.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda al respecto.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="nojs html css_verticalspacer" lang="es-ES">
 <head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="generator" content="2017.1.0.379"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   // Update the 'nojs'/'js' class on the html node
document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace(/\bnojs\b/g, 'js');

// Check that all required assets are uploaded and up-to-date
if(typeof Muse == "undefined") window.Muse = {}; window.Muse.assets = {"required":["museutils.js", "museconfig.js", "jquery.watch.js", "require.js", "index.css"], "outOfDate":[]};
</script>

  <title>Inicio</title>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site_global.css?crc=444006867"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css?crc=4168683600" id="pagesheet"/>
    <!--custom head HTML-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="clearfix" id="page"><!-- group -->
   <div class="textos clearfix grpelem" id="u164-4"><!-- content -->
    <p>titulo</p>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu102-4"><!-- column -->
    <div class="portafolio1 clearfix colelem" id="u102-4"><!-- content -->
     <p>titulo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="portafolio1 clearfix colelem" id="u161-4"><!-- content -->
     <p>titulo</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="texto-descarga clearfix grpelem" id="u167-4"><!-- content -->
    <p>titulo</p>
   </div>
   <div class="verticalspacer" data-offset-top="317" data-content-above-spacer="317" data-content-below-spacer="62"></div>
   <div class="grpelem" id="u98"><!-- custom html -->
    <script>
$('.titulos').addClass('wow bounceInUp');
$('.textos').addClass('wow bounceInUp');
$('.ico-counter').addClass('wow zoomIn’);
$('.texto-counter').addClass('wow lightSpeedIn');
$('.portafolio1').addClass('wow slideInLeft');
$('.portafolio2').addClass('wow slideInUp');
$('.portafolio3').addClass('wow slideInUp');
$('.portafolio4').addClass('wow slideInRight');
$('.portafolio5').addClass('wow slideInRight');
$('.texto-descarga').addClass('wow slideInLeft');
$('.campos-formulario').addClass('wow slideInUp');
$('.boton-formulario').addClass('wow slideInUp');
$('.texto-suscripcion').addClass('wow slideInLeft');
$('.formulario-suscripcion').addClass(‘wow slideInRight');
$('.boton-suscripcion').addClass('wow slideInRight');
</script>
<script>
wow = new WOW(
{
boxClass:     'wow',      // default
animateClass: 'animated', // default
offset:       0,          // default
mobile:       true,       // default
live:         true        // default
}
    )
    wow.init();
</script>
<i></i>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Other scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   // Decide weather to suppress missing file error or not based on preference setting
var suppressMissingFileError = false
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.Muse.assets.check=function(d){if(!window.Muse.assets.checked){window.Muse.assets.checked=!0;var b={},c=function(a,b){if(window.getComputedStyle){var c=window.getComputedStyle(a,null);return c&&c.getPropertyValue(b)||c&&c[b]||""}if(document.documentElement.currentStyle)return(c=a.currentStyle)&&c[b]||a.style&&a.style[b]||"";return""},a=function(a){if(a.match(/^rgb/))return a=a.replace(/\s+/g,"").match(/([\d\,]+)/gi)[0].split(","),(parseInt(a[0])<<16)+(parseInt(a[1])<<8)+parseInt(a[2]);if(a.match(/^\#/))return parseInt(a.substr(1),
16);return 0},g=function(g){for(var f=document.getElementsByTagName("link"),h=0;h<f.length;h++)if("text/css"==f[h].type){var i=(f[h].href||"").match(/\/?css\/([\w\-]+\.css)\?crc=(\d+)/);if(!i||!i[1]||!i[2])break;b[i[1]]=i[2]}f=document.createElement("div");f.className="version";f.style.cssText="display:none; width:1px; height:1px;";document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(f);for(h=0;h<Muse.assets.required.length;){var i=Muse.assets.required[h],l=i.match(/([\w\-\.]+)\.(\w+)$/),k=l&&l[1]?
l[1]:null,l=l&&l[2]?l[2]:null;switch(l.toLowerCase()){case "css":k=k.replace(/\W/gi,"_").replace(/^([^a-z])/gi,"_$1");f.className+=" "+k;k=a(c(f,"color"));l=a(c(f,"backgroundColor"));k!=0||l!=0?(Muse.assets.required.splice(h,1),"undefined"!=typeof b[i]&&(k!=b[i]>>>24||l!=(b[i]&16777215))&&Muse.assets.outOfDate.push(i)):h++;f.className="version";break;case "js":h++;break;default:throw Error("Unsupported file type: "+l);}}d?d().jquery!="1.8.3"&&Muse.assets.outOfDate.push("jquery-1.8.3.min.js"):Muse.assets.required.push("jquery-1.8.3.min.js");
f.parentNode.removeChild(f);if(Muse.assets.outOfDate.length||Muse.assets.required.length)f="Puede que determinados archivos falten en el servidor o sean incorrectos. Limpie la cache del navegador e inténtelo de nuevo. Si el problema persiste, póngase en contacto con el administrador del sitio web.",g&&Muse.assets.outOfDate.length&&(f+="\nOut of date: "+Muse.assets.outOfDate.join(",")),g&&Muse.assets.required.length&&(f+="\nMissing: "+Muse.assets.required.join(",")),suppressMissingFileError?(f+="\nUse SuppressMissingFileError key in AppPrefs.xml to show missing file error pop up.",console.log(f)):alert(f)};location&&location.search&&location.search.match&&location.search.match(/muse_debug/gi)?
setTimeout(function(){g(!0)},5E3):g()}};
var muse_init=function(){require.config({baseUrl:""});require(["jquery","museutils","whatinput","jquery.watch"],function(d){var $ = d;$(document).ready(function(){try{
window.Muse.assets.check($);/* body */
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblemsPreInit();/* body */
Muse.Utils.prepHyperlinks(true);/* body */
Muse.Utils.makeButtonsVisibleAfterSettingMinWidth();/* body */
Muse.Utils.fullPage('#page');/* 100% height page */
Muse.Utils.showWidgetsWhenReady();/* body */
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblems();/* body */
}catch(b){if(b&&"function"==typeof b.notify?b.notify():Muse.Assert.fail("Error calling selector function: "+b),false)throw b;}})})};

</script>
  <!-- RequireJS script -->
  <script src="scripts/require.js?crc=3861931657" type="text/javascript" async data-main="scripts/museconfig.js?crc=533079045" onload="if (requirejs) requirejs.onError = function(requireType, requireModule) { if (requireType && requireType.toString && requireType.toString().indexOf && 0 <= requireType.toString().indexOf('#scripterror')) window.Muse.assets.check(); }" onerror="window.Muse.assets.check();"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Sin probar el código veo que hay un error aquí: `$('.ico-counter').addClass('wow zoomIn’);` utilizando comillas distintas para abrir y cerrar el string.

Comment: Hola Jose, muchas gracias por tu comentario, lo he arreglado, pero parece que sigue igual, siguen sin funcionar las animaciones, estoy por colgarlo en la pagina de prueba en la red, he actualizado java y la controladora de nvidia, persiste el problema, y el caso que todo funcionaba correctamente!

Comment: puedes ver un ejemplo en http://www.laplata.surf

Comment: Como puedes ver no hace nada, y todos los elementos tienen un estilo grafico

Comment: Me sale un error: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Saber más]`. Debes importar jquery.

Comment: eres dios Jose Hermosilla Rodrigo, ahora funciona, aunque aún está por ver en la página real, vuelve a cargar la pagina ahora, en un ratito te cuento si todo va bien

Comment: jejeje aaaay si yo fuera Dios... Me alegro que te funcione! Saludos! =)

Comment: Mira Jose, ahora he cargado la pagina que estoy haciendo, y tengo una preguntita más, como podrás observar, estoy utilizando librerías externas y tambien librerias que cargo en la web, mi pregunta es. Sería recomendable cargar las ultimas actualizaciones de las librerias o eso no implica errores en la pagina?

Comment: en el movil me dice que puede que algunos archivos falten en el servidor, pero en el portatil todo parece ir bien!

Comment: Debes de tener cuidado con el orden en qué importas las librerías, puede ser que algunas dependan de otras. Por ende, debes mirar qué dependencias tienen las librerías que estás usando. Es conveniente siempre estar actualizado en mi opinión, pero has de ser muy cuidadoso, quizás actualizar una librería, si introduce `breaking changes` en su API, hace que tu código deje de funcionar.